# My certificate seems fine but my TLS fails (Cert not validated)

Tags: tls, certificates, email

I set up my certificate for my mail server at https://mail.xxxx.com/ 
I exported my certificate as described in my mail servers documentation and pointed to it in the server settings.

The certificate seems to validate 100% on all tests, even the issuer verified that all is well. However my mail clients like outlook and thunderbird seem to fail with invalid certificate warnings.

You can see it fail at http://www.checktls.com/ if you use the email address support@xxxx.com

```
    [001.838]       
Certificate 1 of 3 in chain:
subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=mail.xxxx.com
issuer= /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA                                                                                                                                                                                
[001.886]       
Certificate 2 of 3 in chain:
subject= /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
issuer= /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority                                                                                                                                                                                  
[001.933]       
Certificate 3 of 3 in chain:
subject= /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
issuer= /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority          Validation Secure Server CA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    [003.400]       Cert NOT VALIDATED: unable to get local issuer certificate
    [003.401]       this may help: What Is An Intermediate Certificate
    [003.401]       So email is encrypted but the domain is not verified
    [005.791]       Cert Hostname VERIFIED (mail.xxxx.com = mail.xxxx.com)
```

Edit : The chain moves to the second certificate but then repeats, and if i look at the chain anywhere else it connects fine.

Im hoping someone can maybe shed light on what the problem is.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You client is looking for the server to provide copies of the intermediate certificates and it appears your server is not doing so.  The exact configuration will vary based on your server, but it should be possible to download the intermediate certificates (from your CA) and share them along with your server certificate in order to get to a certificate that the client trusts.

Basically, the client doesn't want to have to (or is unable to) look up intermediate certificates on the Internet.  Thus, you need to provide them so that each step in the chain can be validated.  Some clients will go out and find them or may already include many common intermediate certs, others do not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the chain is not correct. It looks like there are three certificates but all of them are the same. It looks like you are missing at least the Comodo Intermediate certificate:

```
CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority.
```